# Open Quick Create form on click of "+" button on Opportunity product entity subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, subgrid

We are in a need to open "Quick Create" form on click of the "+" button on OOB Opportunity product subgrid on Opportunity entity.

Following things I have done so far:

1. Enabled Opportunity Product entity "Allow Quick Create".
2. Customised "Add new" button using Ribbon Workbench to add the Javascript action to open quick create form. Using this approach, I found that the JS was not getting executed.

Link referred : https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/219639

Please help to implement the requirement and resolve the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Opportunity Product is a special case, it has its own inline-edit view & 2 different fly-out options in (+) sub-grid button.

Try hiding this inline edit grid & add a new usual sub-grid with modified view like recommended [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/170653). Maintain the name `opportunityproductsGrid`.

Also make sure you are customizing the right (+) button & command, remove the default action & adding the custom command + javascript action to invoke `Xrm.Utility.openQuickCreate`